# Processing a queue of jobs via PHP, but faster than cron's 1-minute minimum?

Tags: php, cron

Many users upload photos to my site, and at peak times the load of resizing and saving the photos causes my server to run out of memory and MySQL to crash.

I figure I can detach the processing from the uploading, and instead of having many concurrent reloads happening I can just have one job doing them one-by-one, which should hugely reduce my memory needs.

But how best to implement this?

My first thought was just a cronjob that runs repeatedly and checks for any unprocessed files. But a cronjob can only (I think) run every minute, so sometimes there would be a large delay even if a user uploaded just one photo at a quiet time on the site.

I expect this is a fairly common problem, so what's the solution?

(I'd rather do this myself with minimal code rather than use a huge third party library, if possible.)

Thanks

Comment: cron every minute, sleep(), time(), loop

Comment: The best way to write minimal code is to use the huge third-party libraries.

Comment: @ceejayoz :) :) That has some logic

Comment: Side note: We use the quite inexpensive http://imgix.com/ for this. You could also build it with something like Amazon S3 + Lambda cheaply and efficiently.

Comment: Blindingly obvious, thanks.  Though now I'm thinking that hitting the database every second to check for unprocessed files isn't very efficient.  Maybe I could create an empty file when a photo is uploaded and check for the existence of that file instead, and then delete the file once all items are processed?

Comment: you could also check the current queue and the amount of uploaded images; if it is less then the number of photo's you deem to be 'safe'; do it right away, otherwise put them on the queue and let the cronjob handle it

Comment: Do your user expect to see the results instantly?

Comment: I'm sure some will and some won't Riggs.  I always try to be as performant and instant as I can, because I know I'm the sort of person that likes things to be snappy... I'd agree that a small delay of a minute isn't necessarily a big deal though.  But if I can (relatively easily) avoid it, I'd prefer to.